# Java clip decrease/increase volume depending on distance

Tags: java, audio, volume, clip

Hello I'm writing a game and I want to change volume of one actor depending on distance between player and the actor. I'm playing the sound in loop.

my sound class:

```
public class Sound {

    private Clip clip;
    private FloatControl volume;

    public Sound(String path) {
        loadMusic(path);
    }

    public void loadMusic(String path) {

        clip = null;
        if (!path.equals("")) {

            File soundFile = null;

            try {
                soundFile = new File(path);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }

            try {
                AudioInputStream input = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                clip = null;
            }
            volume = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);

        }

    }

    public void play() {
        if (clip != null) {
            stop();
            clip.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (clip != null) {
            if (clip.isRunning()) {
                clip.stop();
            }
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
        }
    }

    public void loop() {
        if (clip != null) {
            clip.loop(clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        }
    }

    public void setVolume(float vol) {
        volume = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        if (volume.getMinimum() + vol <= volume.getMaximum()) {
            volume.setValue(volume.getMinimum());
            volume.setValue(volume.getMinimum() + vol);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's where i'm checking distance:

```
public float getDistance(int x, int y) {
        return (float)(Math.sqrt( Math.pow((this.x + this.getWidth() - x), 2) + Math.pow((this.y + this.getHeight() - y), 2)));
    }



//this is checked every loop im game. 
float distance = getDistance(actor.getX() + actor.getWidth(), actor.getY() + actor.getHeight());
    if (distance <= 100) {
        play.setVolume(2000/distance);
    }
    else 
        play.setVolume(0f);
```

I know that getDistane is working correctly and I know that volume.getValue() is changing smoothly but sound isn't. It's more like it waits when one loop ends and then it change volume.